Why did worm-like lobopodians go extinct but polychaete worms thrive?
Obviously lobopodians are not extinct in the same way dinosaurs are not extinct (because of birds) - arthropods, tardigrades and velvet worms are all lobopodians.
But at the same time, there are no lobopodians occupying the marine worms-with-legs ecological niche - tardigrades are miniaturized, velvet worms are terrestrial, and arthropods generally have moved away from wormy shapes (maybe remipedes have undifferentiated segments).
At the same time, their ecological niche is obviously not defunct, but is occupied by polychaete worms. In fact, the old (and wrong) Articulata hypothesis comes because polychaete annelids look a lot like what arthropods should have evolved from - worms with stubby legs. And arthropods did evolve from worms with stubby legs, it's just that those worms were lobopodians instead of annelids.
So I guess my question is - similar to how today there are birds but not pterodactyls, why are there extant polychaete worms but no extant worm-like lobopodians - even though their body-type is essentially the same? Lobopodians were widespread during the Cambrian, did polychaete worms just outcompete them somehow?

No expert, but I'm not sure "Why" is answerable, other than with "Because they did" unless there's some direct evidence that there is a likely cause, such as with the Chicxulub impact and dinosaurs.

I assume polychates must have had some kind of an advantage. Another question is how long did lobopodians last - they are known mostly from the Cambrian but they might have lasted until the Carboniferous - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982212007427

In that case, there have been many mass-extinction events and we have lost quite a few whole lineages over the intervening time, including such long-lasting and abundant organisms as the artiopoda (which includes trilobites) and was around since the Cambrian right through to the Permian/Triassic extinction.

It could simply be that there's a paucity of specimens as the conditions needed to preserve them in fossils are relatively rare and as such we can't deduce much from the ones we do have.
